# Snap.svg and javascript throws Uncaught SyntaxError

Tags: javascript, jquery, snap.svg

I have a problem with Snap.svg and javascript. I'm trying to animate an svg on mouseEnter event, but I'm getting an error when an event is fired:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier localhost/:3 Uncaught
>   SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Inside of this error I find:

```
(function(val
     /**/) {
     return Snap.path.toString.call([[object Array]])            //error in this line
})
```

My code looks like this:

```
 function init() {
    var speed = 250,
        easing = mina.easeinout;

    [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.gallery  figure')).forEach(function(el) {


            var s = Snap(el.querySelector('svg')),
                path = s.select('path'),
                pathConfig = {
                    from: path.attr('d'),
                    to: el.getAttribute('data-path-hover')
                };

            el.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
                path.animate({
                    'path': pathConfig.to
                }, speed, easing);

            });

            el.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
                path.animate({
                    'path': pathConfig.from
                }, speed, easing);
            });
        });
}
```

Comment: Any chance you could put an example on a jsfiddle ?

Comment: http://generictec.com/demo/ONE/
The gallery section blue overlay should change shape on mouse over.

Comment: No idea which is the gallery on there, the projects page ? I don't get any errors on there? Quite a lot of that page is broken in Opera btw.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently error exists only on OS X chrome beta, nowhere else does it happen. I'll wait for next chrome update and see if it gets resolved.